# My pygame window keeps crashing and I'm following a youtube tutorial, on mac

Tags: python, pygame

I'm very new to python and I've been following Tech With Tim's pygame tutorial, but my window isn't responding or closing. I'm using a mac and I don't know if that changes anything... and I keep getting the error message

Error:

`function missing required argument 'rect' (pos 3)`.

Code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("First game")

x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel
    
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please post the full error message, including the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

`rect` function takes at least three arguments, only 2 were given:

```
pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
```

It should work on mac too

Check pygame docs for reference : https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have not typed it's height width x position and y position where you drew the rectangle do this

```
pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, height, width))
```

You have `x`, `y`, `height`, `width` already defined this should work.